# Error log full of 'Starting up database 'xxx'

Tags: sql-server-2008

My sql error log is full of messages telling me one or another of my dbs is starting up - sometimes the time spacing is only fractions of a sec apart:

```
2010-08-27 10:07:00.98 spid59      Starting up database 'myDb'.
2010-08-27 10:07:03.11 spid59      Starting up database 'myDb'.
2010-08-27 10:07:03.44 spid59      Starting up database 'myDb'.
```

I'm seeing this on several db that have very low activity and on seeing any on thoes dbs that are more active.  No intervening messages saying anything about an error condition - is this normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the properties of your database.
If "**AutoClose**" is on the database will shut down after the last connection is closed.

It is recommended to set **Autoclose** to false.